# string operations in Lua

Tags: string, replace, lua

I have a string in which I have to replace some characters (or to delete, which is the same here). The important part is marked by the character `@`. the charcters before it should be replaced by the following ones, independet on the number of characters before and behing the `@`. The end of the string on the right side of `@` is given by line end or the characters `!` and `|` .
Some examples

```
str0 = "whatever"                 -- do nothing
str1 = "whatever!whenever!time"   -- do nothing
--
-- the following should replace only "little" by "big"
-- means "little@big"  -> "big"
--
str2 = "little@big"  
str3 = "Size!little@big"
str4 = "Whatever!Size!little@big!whatever"
str5 = "Whatever!little@big!whatever!little@big"
str5 = "Whatever!little@big!whatever!little@big!little@big"
str6 = "Whatever!little@big!whatever!little@big!little@big|foo"
```

the numbers of `@` is not known. Is there an "easy" code to modify the string?

Comment: In what string "little" should be replaced by "big"?

Comment: In my real code I do not know which kind of string I have to handle. All of the above examples are possible. That is my problem. `function changeStr(str)` should return `str` with the replaced chracters.

Comment: So you want only what comes after the `@` character? If there can be more than one, do you use the first or last one? (`first@second@third` -> `third` or `second@third`?)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Thanks, works fine! You should give it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = str:gsub('[^!|@%s]+@', '')
```